# Passing fxml objects between two seperate controller classes javafx fxml

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I have two seperate stages (mainStage, popupStage), both with their own controller class and associated fxml file.

I would like to access some buttons defined with the @FXML annotation in mainStage's controller, from popupStage's controller. I've found that using `loader.getController()` to create an instance of the controller that has all the fxml button objects, then passing it to the popupScene's controller, and simply calling `mainStageControllerInstance.reset();` from the popupStage controller would be a viable solution. I've managed to create a mainStageController instance using this approach, however, the buttons retrieved from this instance weren't the same ones that were being displayed on the mainStage at runtime. Therefore I am only able to affect the buttons from the mainStage controller class, and not by calling the @FXML reset() method from the popupStage controller, and adding the buttons retrieved from the `loader.getController()` object.

Creating the mainStageControllerInstance object:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main_scene.fxml"));
AnchorPane root = loader.load();
mainStageController mainStageControllerInstance  = loader.getController();
```

I've tried adding this code to multiple different classes/methods of the program in hopes that I would be able to reference the buttons displayed on mainStage, and modify them by the click of a button on the popup, but nothing seemed to work.

I have checked all related questions that I came accross that seemingly answered my question, but nothing worked. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of anyone who comes across this post in the future, this is how I managed to solve the issue:

The following method creates mainStage's scene using the fxml file as root.

```
public Scene getMainStageScene() throws Exception {
    
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main_stage.fxml"));    
    Scene mainStageScene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
    
return mainStageScene;
```

}

To obtain the object that has access to all elements injected by FXML, I modified the code above the following way:

```
public Scene getMainStageScene() throws Exception {
    
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("main_stage.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

//defined as: public static mainStage mainStageControllerInstance; before this method
    mainStageControllerInstance = loader.getController(); 

    Scene mainStageScene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
    
return mainStageScene;
```

}

And now I am able to access/modify the objects displayed on mainStage from everywhere in the program, including the popup window.